# redirect vhost with docker-apache-php

Tags: php, docker, apache, docker-compose, vhosts

I'm trying to learn the vhost in docker with php-apache(i'm on windows). So i created a simple project but my vhost does not work :

In test/index.php :

```
<?php

 echo "Hello !";
```

In test/docker/docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.8'

services:

php:
  container_name: php7.2
  build:
    context: ./php7.2
  ports:
    - "9070:80"
  volumes:
    - ../:/var/www/app
    - ./vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

In test/docker/php7.2/Dockerfile :

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN echo "ServerName local.dev" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    git \
    # ZIP
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    # GD
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libpng-dev  \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    # INTL
    libicu-dev && \
    # COMPOSER
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin -- 
    filename=composer && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd \
        --with-gd \
        --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ \
        --with-png-dir=/usr/include/ \
        --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ && \
      docker-php-ext-configure intl && \
      docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
        gd \
        intl \
        pdo_mysql \
        opcache \
        zip

# APCU
RUN pecl install apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu

# XDEBUG
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# APACHE
RUN a2enmod rewrite

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

WORKDIR /var/www/app/
```

In test/docker/vhosts/local.dev.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName local.dev

DocumentRoot /var/www/app
DirectoryIndex /index.php

<Directory /var/www/app>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/test_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/test_access.log combined
```

Of course i added 127.0.0.1 local.dev in my host file. When i try http://127.0.0.1:9070 everything works but when i try http://local.dev:9070 the browser redirects to https://local.dev:9070 and i get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

I don't understand why I am redirected. Did I forget something ?

Comment: Does your folder 'sites-enabled' contain 'default-ssl.conf' or any other config files? Did you try to open url in anonymous browser window (sometimes it remember https redirects)?

Comment: now, sites-enabled contains only local.dev.conf. However, sites-available contains default-ssl-conf. I tried in anonymous, no success !

Comment: ok, dont use domain in .dev with chrome, just test with .local and it works !